# Magento 2 setup:di:compile not work when create Interface and Repository

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.4, fatal-error

When i try to start command setup:di:compile i see this error:

[image]

Uncaught Error: Interface 'WebbyTroops\Subscription\Api\SubscriptionRepositoryInterface' not found in /var/www/html/hajery/app/code/Hajery/Subscription/Model/SubscriptionRepository.php:18 but
and this is the file SubscriptionRepository.php:

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use WebbyTroops\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription as SubscriptionResource;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use WebbyTroops\Subscription\Api\Data\SubscriptionInterface;
use WebbyTroops\Subscription\Api\SubscriptionRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * @class SubscriptionRepository
 */
class SubscriptionRepository implements SubscriptionRepositoryInterfaceEnter
{
    /**
     * @var SubscriptionResource
     */
    protected $resource;

    /**
     * @var SubscriptionFactory
     */
    protected $subscriptionFactory;

    /*
     * @var \WebbyTroops\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $subscriptionCollectionFactory;

    /*
     * @var \WebbyTroops\Subscription\Api\Data\SubscriptionSearchResultsInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $searchResultsFactory;

    /*
     * @var CollectionProcessorInterface
     */
    protected $collectionProcessor;

    /**
     * @param SubscriptionResource $resource
     * @param SubscriptionFactory $subscriptionFactory
     * @param \WebbyTroops\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\CollectionFactory $subscriptionCollectionFactory
     * @param \WebbyTroops\Subscription\Api\Data\SubscriptionSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactorys
     * @param CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor
     */
    public function __construct(
        SubscriptionResource $resource,
        SubscriptionFactory $subscriptionFactory,
        \WebbyTroops\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\CollectionFactory $subscriptionCollectionFactory,
        \WebbyTroops\Subscription\Api\Data\SubscriptionSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $searchResultsFactory,
        CollectionProcessorInterface $collectionProcessor
    ) {
        $this->resource              = $resource;
        $this->subscriptionFactory   = $subscriptionFactory;
        $this->subscriptionCollectionFactory = $subscriptionCollectionFactory;
        $this->searchResultsFactory  = $searchResultsFactory;
        $this->collectionProcessor   = $collectionProcessor;
    }
}
```

I tried to search but i have not found anything abaout this issue.
How can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Class name of the above file is wrong .On above question namespace is  `namespace Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader;` it should be `WebbyTroops\Subscription\Model` and it should exit at var`/www/html/hajery/app/code/WebbyTroops/Subscription` and di.xml should be updated based on above.